# AJAX Response Error: [object Object] ASP.net web core application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-webpages

In my view I am calling AJAX post to a function in controller passing data but what I am getting error response and I think that is not arriving to the function in the controller.

**View**

```
var course = "programming";
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  url: '/Schedule/GetData',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: {
    coursename: course
  },
  success: function(response) {
    // Generate HTML table.  
    //convertJsonToHtmlTable(JSON.parse(response), $("#TableId"));

    alert(response);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    alert("Error: " + response);
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult GetData(string coursename) {

  var teachers = mydb.schedules.Where(s =>s.coursename == coursename).Select(s =>s.coursename);

  return Json(teachers, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());
}
```

Comment: You didn't decorate your action method with [HttpPost] method.

Comment: @noobprogrammer No I wrote [HttpPost] and it didn't work

Comment: try removing the / and try this: url: 'Schedule/GetData'

Comment: @MohammadFarfour I hope you have build your project (Ctrl + Shift + B) and then checked.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I treid that and it didn't work

Comment: @noobprogrammer I rebuilded it still same error

Comment: Change the action name from GetData to something else. .NET Core will interpret it as Get method instead of Post.

Comment: @noobprogrammer I tried it now still same error and i think it is not routed to the function i tried to put console.writeline in function to check , nothing is printed

Comment: @noobprogrammer what i am trying to do is to populate a dropdown list from database based on a ajax post method with a specific variable is there another way to do that?

Comment: Try to modify this line `url: '/Schedule/GetData'`. You must write it as `url: '/Schedule/GetData?coursename=' +coursename `. It was not getting the coursename in the action method that is why you were facing issue